# Difficulty Understanding Oracle DQL Procedures and Functions Coming from T-SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, plsql

I am much more familiar with SQL Server, but I am doing a project now in Oracle. There is a concept from SQL Server that I am not sure how to accomplish in Oracle.

In SQL Server if I create a procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetSomeStuff
(    
    @start_date DATE
    @end_date DATE
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
  Customer
, SUM( WidgetsPurchased ) AS WidgetsPurchased
FROM WidgetSales
WHERE TransactionDate >= @start_date
  AND TransactionDate <= @end_date
GROUP BY
  Customer
END
```

(Imagine a more complex query is involved). This gives application code a clean interface for 'selecting' this data without getting involved in a bunch of SQL. The application can just run `usp_GetSomeStuff '2018-01-01', 2018-12-31'` and get the results.

Oracle, on the other hand has a separation between the procedural language and the database language, and this is quite foreign to me.

When you are inside of a PL/SQL block you cannot perform DQL (unless assigning to cursors or variable).

For example, this is not legal:

```
create or replace procedure get_some_stuff
(
      in_start_date date
    , in_end_date date
)
is
begin
    select
      customer
    , sum( widgets_purchased ) as widgets_purchased
    from widgetsales
    where transactiondate >= in_start_date
      and transactiondate <= in_end_date
    group by
      customer
    ;
end;
/
```

`PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`

What is the 'Oracle Way' way of 'wrapping' a complex query for a caller that wants the results as if the caller had executed the select statement itself?

Note that we could also do this in a table valued function in SQL Server, which is even more convenient sometimes because we can call it as

```
select
 only
,these
,columns
from GetSomeStuff('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
where xyz = 123
```

With Oracle I just don't 'get it'. What's the pattern for doing this kind of thing in Oracle?

I am using Oracle 12c.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: A view does not take input parameters. That is why I specifically added the start date and end date parameters to my example. A view can not accomplish my example because it aggregates differently for different inputs.

Comment: Using 12c, will edit the question to include this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle supports "table valued functions" as well. However they need a lot more boiler plate code than one would like. The main (annoying) "problem" is, that you need to explicitly define a type that can be returned:

```
create type stuff_type as object
(
  customer varchar(50),
  widgets_purchased number
)
/

create stuff_list as table of stuff_type
/


create function get_stuff(p_start_date date, p_end_date date)
   return stuff_list
   pipelined
as
begin
  for rec in (select customer, sum(widgets_purchased) as widgets_purchased
              from widgetsales
              where transactiondate >= p_start_date
                and transactiondate <= p_end_date
              group by customer) 
  loop
    pipe row stuff_type(rec.customer, rec.widgets_purchased);     
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The usage is also a bit different:

```
select *
from table(get_stuff(current_date - 7, current_date));
```

Some more examples and insights can be found here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

---

Starting with Oracle 12.1 you can also use implicit results:

```
create or replace procedure get_stuff(p_start_date date, p_end_date date)
as
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;  
BEGIN
  OPEN c1 FOR 
    select customer, sum(widgets_purchased) as widgets_purchased
    from widgetsales
    where transactiondate >= p_start_date
      and transactiondate <= p_end_date
    group by customer;

  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c1);
END;
/
```

Some more details and examples for implicit results: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1

Answer (score 0):

The first thing would be to research the error message that Oracle provided.  That should lead to the understanding that, in PL/SQL, any SELECT has to have a variable into which it will place the result of the select. (Actually, all programming languages do. That's just fundamental.  But in this case PL/SQL, like a lot of languages, makes you explicitly declare it instead of just making assumptions and doing it for you behind the curtain.) The type of the variable will depend on what is being returned from the select.  The next thing, as others have pointed out, is that the procedure has to declare the output parameters.  The examples that others gave are just that, examples. There are many other types available.  You need to spend some more time in the [PL/SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm), and looking at examples on other websites.  A good source of a lot of examples for Oracle "stuff" is [www.oracle-base.com.](https://oracle-base.com/)